# Has anyone noticed a recent update that affects ShapeRange.Export ppShapeFormatPNG is now exporting transparent backgrounds with black background?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I'm using some code that I've posted on this forum before that has worked perfectly for months - ShapeRange.Export ppShapeFormatPNG. I have setting in the VBA macro that export my shapes as a PNG with transparent background. But it seems that a recent update from something (system or app etc.) has interfered and now the PNGs are exporting with a black background instead.

The reason I'm deducing that it's because of an update is that I used a different computer where I don't have the updates and when using the same file, I'm able to get the transparent backgrounds exported.

Has anyone else seen this? Does anyone know which update or app is interfering and causing the background to export black?

Thank you!

Comment: This was created 2 weeks ago - does it help in doing it manually? https://nutsandboltsspeedtraining.com/powerpoint-tutorials/remove-background-from-image/

Comment: Unfortunately no - I have the macro because I have to process hundreds of images through PPT. But thank you!

Comment: Well my point is that if it works manually that way, then you can automate it.. it's just a start

Comment: at least try it... see if you can get it to work manually... then go from there - you dont seem to have many other options

Comment: I see, thanks - the problem is that my macro stitches together a dozen images in different sizes and configurations. The individual images that come in have transparent background, which means the export of the stitched image should also have transparent background. This has worked for months, and then all of sudden now it's exporting with a black background. The article you sent would require further changes to the image that I export. I'd have to import that new stitched image to remove the backgound which is inefficient. The macro works on an older laptop, so it must be a recent update.

Comment: I would have to agree that it because of the update, but since everyone is going to be forced to use the update eventually, it would make sense to put forth the effort to update your code as well (somehow) - or find an alternative - sorry.

Answer (score 0):

After much digging, it was an Office 365 update.

I rolled back my Office 365 to version 12026.20320 and now my macro is exporting images with transparent background instead of with black background. It was at the latest version 12228.20206.

There is a very helpful article on CNET that shows you how to rollback Office 365 updates:
https://www.cnet.com/how-to/how-to-revert-to-the-previous-version-of-office-365/